# How to add a file/edit/view... bar into polybar?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, i3

I am using i3-gaps for a desktop environment. I try to configure polybar to have *file/edit/view...* bar with a name of a focused app (like in a mac topbar). I am using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality that could do this in polybar.

---

In theory, if there is some standard API that exposes information about the *file/edit/view...* menus for the currently focused application, you could write a script to emulate such behavior in the [script module](https://github.com/jaagr/polybar/wiki/Module:-script).

This however would not be a small task. You would also need a way to actually display the several menu layers (this cannot be done with polybar itself).